# boost unordered_map key value of 0

Tags: c++, boost, unordered-map

I am using boost 1.56 and have an unordered_map. When I insert a key value of zero as follows:

```
boost::unordered_map<int, int> map;
for(int i=0; i < size; i++)
{
   int value = another_array[j];
   map.insert(i, value);
}
```

I get a crash when accessing the map using 
    map.at(0);

I've tested that the insert works by looking at the 
    std::pairiterator, bool>

that the insert returns and the bool is true, indicating that it was successfully inserted
I am creating a local to global numbering map so my keys are all 0:N-1. I know N and so should be able to loop over (count == 0:N-1) as follows:

```
for(int j=0; j < count; j++)
{
    if(map.count(j))
        printf("Value at index %d is %d\n", j, map.at(j)); 
}
```

but the count of k is zero. If I don't perform the check I get an out of bounds error. How can this be happening? If I switch to using 1-N as keys there is no such problem.

I do realise btw that in this example a map is slight overkill, but I have my reasons.

Note that I can not use std::unordered map as we are cross platform and our linux compiler doesn't currently support it.

Comment: Have you tried `for(auto& entry:map) std::cout<<e.first<<", "<<e.second<<"\n";`?

Comment: Re: EDIT, please make a selfconatined example that shows the error for you.

Comment: well, not exactly as I can't use c++11, but I did try to use the boost::unordered_map<int,int>::iterator which I typedef's as ii_iter, and this: `for(ii_iter i = map.begin(); i!= map.end(); i++) printf("key: %d value %d\n", i->first(), i->second)` and it doesn't print the 0 (I needed the test described above in there) and also falls off the end of the map

Comment: that's a yes. So, what did it print? Did you use _at the same point  where you call `at(0)`_?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**Before edit**: Most likely your hash<> specialization ***or*** equality comparison for `key_type` is broken.

You don't show it, but only this kind of invariant-breaking error can explain the behaviour you describe (in a self-contained minimal example), as far as I can tell.

**After edit:** You should create a self-contained example that shows the error for you, for us to be able to come up with better diagnostics

Comment: the map is <int, int> - is the default equality comparison really that bad in boost? I suppose the hash could be bad. I am just using the default hash function

Comment: @mike not at all. This is why since the edit, you really need to come up with that SSCCE

Comment: @mike Good luck. On the bright side, this _always_ leads to the answer. Eventually. http://java.dzone.com/articles/solve-your-problem-almost

Comment: You're right of course. I found it! I am building a topology and have another unordered_map<int, int*>, the int*'s are all 4 ints long. I eventually collate all the int*'s together into one single int*, which I was under allocating (using the size of the map rather than size*4).

Answer (score 0):

Answer found thanks to sehe  forcing me to write self contained code. This showed up an under allocation of an array further up, overwrites past the end of this were causing the normal memory wierdness and this was just a symptom.

Comment: In case you're on a platform that allows it, valgrind or the memory sanitizers in clang/gcc would have told you this. Also, some static analysis tools would probably have guessed that `sizeof(map)` isn't what you intended

Answer (score 0):

at doesn't take index as a parameter. It takes a key as parameter. If there is no item inserted with key "0", boost will throw exception which results in crash.

http://www.boost.org/doc/libs/1_48_0/doc/html/boost/unordered_map.html#id1601722-bb